# Balanced Parenthesis:

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to solve a problem of balanced parenthesis but getting error. I don't know why I am getting wrong answer as my logic is fine. I am trying to solve it for a long time but can't get any way. This is my code in java:

```
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=sc.nextInt();

        for(int i=0; i<n;i++){
             Stack<Character> stack=new Stack<Character>();
        char x,y;
           for(int j=0; j<stack.size();j++){ 
           x=sc.next().charAt(j);
           y=stack.peek();
           if(x=='{' || x=='[' || x=='('){
                stack.push(x);
            }

            if(x=='}'){
                if(y=='{'){
                    stack.pop();
                //    System.out.println("Yes");
                }
               // else{
                 //   System.out.println("No");
               //}

            }else if(x==']'){
                if(y=='['){
                    stack.pop();

                }
            }else if(x==')'){   
                if(y=='('){
                    stack.pop();
                //    System.out.println("Yes");
                }
            }
          }
         if(stack.empty()==true){
         System.out.println("YES");

    }else if(stack.empty()!=true){
         System.out.println("NO");   
        }
    }


    }
}
```

Comment: There is no error. I am getting wrong answer for several test cases. Test case: 3                                                                                                             {[()]}
{[(])}
{{[[(())]]}}                                                                                                         For the above test case it should print YES NO YES but it is printing YES YES YES

Comment: well, your first sentence mentions an error...

Comment: Fix your indenting. If your code "ends up too far to the right": split out a method. Without a specification of the input (or, at least, a link), we can but guess: stare at `sc.next().charAt(j)`;

Comment: It might be a good idea to make the balanced-parens check a `bool` function and print "yes" or "no" according to the return value. At the moment, your check is based only on the state of the stack at the end, but you miss out on the cases where the wrong type of bracket is on the stack. You also should check for stack underflow.

Comment: what is wrong with sc.next.charAt(j)? I didn't get your point.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Java, but the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) say that `sc.next` gets the next token (or "word") from the stream. That means you advance two things: the token and the letter. Yet one more point in favour of writing a separate function that tests the balance of a single string: You could then easlily pass `sc.next` as argument and do all you checking on the same string, which currently you don't.

Answer (score 0):

```
Stack<Character> stack=new Stack<Character>();
char x,y;
for(int j=0; j<stack.size();j++){
```

The initial size of the stack is zero. When your code reaches this section, it checks if `j` (0) is less than `stack.size()` (also 0). Since it's not, it skips the loop, and goes to your ending condition. You want to be looping over the entire `String` you read in.

You probably want to change your code to something like this:

```
Stack<Character> stack=new Stack<Character>();
char x,y;
String text = sc.next();
for(int j = 0; j < text.length(); j++){ 
    x=text.charAt(j);
```

There's also a problem with `stack.peek()` before anything is put into the stack, which throws an exception. You should check for that case with something like this:

```
y = stack.empty() ? '\0' : stack.peek();
```

Which will use a default value (that will never match a closing bracket) if there's nothing on the stack.

Comment: I have changed the code, they way that you have told me. Now no output is coming.

Comment: @RaquibaSultana There was a bug with your `stack.peek()` section. I've added a fix for that part.

Comment: One more thing: [use Deque](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html): _A more complete and consistent set of LIFO stack operations is provided by the `Deque` interface and its implementations, which should be used in preference to this class._ (Avoid legacy classes and deprecated parts.)